# MongoDB : "Couldn't add user : Could not find role"

Tags: mongodb, roles

I'm trying to create a role and an user for my MongoDB database.
I created the role, but when I try to create the user I get this error : "Couldn't add user : Could not find role XXX ". Ok ... But when I try to create the role again, mongo tells me the role already exists. What am I suppose to do please ? It's a school project, I'm not familiar with MongoDB.

[MongoDB errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meEde.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added some extra spaces in your database name: `" cubesdb "`.

Try `"cubesdb"`

Comment: Yes, I figured out after few hours haha. I need new glasses !Btw it still didnt work because of the line "  roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "cubesdb"}] " even if it was in all the tutos ive seen. If someone has this issue aswell you need to delete the code between []

Comment: In which database did you create the user? Typically you use the `admin` database for that, perhaps you created them somewhere else.